# Format Integer value into UK digit format

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a integer value, which should be formatted to uk number digit format

```
int a = 526558;
int data = a.ToString("n0");
```

but i want

```
a = 5,26,558;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the numeric formatting `n0` for "number with 0 decimals" and the `en-GB` culture:

```
int a = 526558;

string aFormatted = a.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));

Console.WriteLine(aFormatted);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx